# Why does my excel spreadsheet omit the 0's after the decimal point?

Tags: microsoft-excel

The programme does not record the value as I type it in.

I am working with financial values and need the programme to record the zeros (corresponding to pence) after the decimal point to two places.

Answer (score 2):

Have you highlighted the column and changed the number formatting from the default of General?

Highlight column or cell, Right Click Menu -> Format Cells -> Numeric

And change to Number or Currency and choose number of decimal places as 2